# Accessing std::map iterators inside range based loop like for_each

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach

Since range based loops are in fashion so I was trying to figure out how to write the following piece of code in an efficient way, which uses range based loop.

But please feel free to restructure code and/or suggest another construct which might be considered a better approach towards processing consecutive keys of a std::map

C++11 compatible answers are preferred, but just for knowledge sake please feel free to recommend anything from boost or C++14

```
void mapRangeLoop()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> infoMap;

// **** Piece of Code to be improved BEGIN *********
  std::for_each(infoMap.rbegin(), infoMap.rend(), [&infoMap](auto& it) {

    auto prev = std::prev(infoMap.find(it.first)); // <---I would like to avoid use of find() to get the iterator

    if (prev != infoMap.end() && isSubString(prev->first, it.first))
      for (auto& p : prev->second)
        processVectors(p, it.second);
  });
// **** Piece of Code to be improved END *********

// Same thing could be achieved through traditional for loop like this
  for (auto it = infoMap.rbegin(); it != infoMap.rend(); ++it)
  {
    auto prev = std::next(it);
    if (prev != infoMap.rend() && isSubString(prev->first, it->first))
      for (auto& p : prev->second)
        processVectors(p, it->second);
  }
}

//Just for completeness
bool isSubString(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
  // returns true or false based on some logic
}

void processVectors(const int i, std::vector<int>& vec)
{
  // Some logic to modify vec based on value of i
}
```

Comment: A range based loop on a `std::map` would provide you with `std::pair<const Key,Value>`.

Comment: It seems you want [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find).

Answer (score 0):

Both range based loop and `std::foreach` are designed to process the elements on their own, independent from others. If you need an iterator to other elements, you need to provide it explicitly:

```
auto next = infoMap.begin();
for(auto& prev: infoMap)
{
    ++next; // now points to element succeeding prev...
    if(next != infoMap.end())
    {
        // your code...
    }
}
```

Range based loop does not iterate in reverse order, though, but the idea in the end is the same:

```
auto next = infoMap.rbegin(); 
std::for_each(infoMap.rbegin(), infoMap.rend(), [&infoMap, &next](auto& prev)
{
    ++next; // again one in advance compared to prev...
            // (other direction than in above loop, though!)
    if(next != infoMap.rend())
    {
        // your code...
    }
});
```

I personally would stay with the classic loop, though – it has the advantage that you can move the `if` out of it:

```
if(infoMap.size() >= 2)
{
    for (auto next = std::next(infoMap.rbegin()); next != infoMap.rend(); ++next)
    {
        prev = std::prev(next);
        // your code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It s, It f ) { return {std::move(s), std::move(f)}; }
```

this is a minimal type to support `for(:)` loops over arbitrary ranges.

Next what I call an indexing iteroid:

```
template<class V>
struct indexing_iteroid {
  using self=indexing_iteroid;
  V value;

  // * just returns a copy of value
  V operator*() const& { return value; }
  V operator*()&&{ return std::move(value); }

  // ++ forwards to value:
  self& operator++() {
    ++value;
    return *this;
  }
  self operator++(int) {
    auto r = *this;
    ++*this;
    return r;
  }

  // == compares values:
  friend bool operator==(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(self const& lhs, self const& rhs) {
    return lhs.value != rhs.value;
  }
};
```

if you wanted to you could extend this to a full-fledged input iterator; categies beyond this in practice require a backing container.

But this iteroid is good enough for `for(:)` loops, which are not specified in terms of iteratore categories but rather specific operations.

```
template<class It>
range_t< indexing_iterator<It> > index_over_range( range_t<It> r ) {
  return {{r.begin()}, {r.end()}};
}
```

this takes a range and creates a range over the iterators in it.

```
for (auto it : index_over_range( range( infoMap.begin(), infoMap.end() ) ) )
{
}
```

now this is a `for(:)` loop which visits each *iterator* into `infoMap`, not each *element* of `infoMap`.

We can clean this up a bit with more boilerplate

```
namespace adl {
  namespace it_details {
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    template<class X>
    auto adl_begin( X&& x )
    -> decltype( begin( std::forward<X>(x) ) )
    { return begin( std::forward<X>(x) ); }
    template<class X>
    auto adl_end( X&& x )
    -> decltype( end( std::forward<X>(x) ) )
    { return end( std::forward<X>(x) ); }
  }
  template<class X>
  auto begin( X&& x )
  -> decltype( it_details::adl_begin( std::forward<X>(x) ) )
  { return it_details::adl_begin( std::forward<X>(x) ); }
  template<class X>
  auto end( X&& x )
  -> decltype( it_details::adl_end( std::forward<X>(x) ) )
  { return it_details::adl_end( std::forward<X>(x) ); }
}
```

this gives is `adl::begin( x )` (and `adl::end( x )`) which invokes `begin` on `x` in a context where `std::begin` is available, but so is argument dependent lookup of `begin`.  This almost perfectly matches how `for(:)` loops find their begin/end iterators.

```
template<class C>
auto iterators_of( C& c )
-> decltype( index_over_range( range( adl::begin(c), adl::end(c) ) ) )
{ return index_over_range( range( adl::begin(c), adl::end(c) ) ); }
```

now `iterators_of(someMap)` returns a range of all the iterators into `someMap`:

```
for (auto it : iterators_of( infoMap ) )
{
}
```

and we have nice, clean efficient syntax.

As an aside, `indexing_iteroid` can also be used to create a counting iteroid (so a for loop visits 0, 1, 2, 3) like:

```
using counting_iteroid = indexing_iteroid<std::size_t>;
auto zero_to_ten = range( counting_iteroid{0}, counting_iteroid{11} );
for (auto x : zero_to_ten) {
   std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

the above probably has some typos.

There is a category of types for which `indexing_iteroid` can wrap; both integers and iterators pass this concept.  You can enhance `indexing_iteroid` to be closer to random access, but due to flaws in how the random access iterator concept was standardized it doesn't let you reach a higher iterator category tha input iterator.  [c++2a](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a)'s Rangesv3 may fix this.